# Get tweets about certain items from a specific user

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

So I want to get historical tweets of a specific user talking about an item or containing this item I tried this code but it always gives me 0 tweets however I'm sure that the user had tweeted about this item

```
tweetCount = 0
item='trump'
with  open('historicalTweetsAboutItem.txt','w') as f:
    for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name='userScreenName', tweet_mode="extended").items():
        tweet=  status.full_text.encode('utf-8')        
        print(tweet)
        if item in tweet:
            f.write(tweet+ "\n")
            tweetCount += 1
print("Downloaded {0} tweets".format(tweetCount))
f.close()
```

Could someone gives me an easier way to get what I want plz :)

Comment: how are you sure that the user had tweeted about this item? Did the `print(tweet)` prints the tweet text and it contains the `item` you want?

Comment: FYI `with` statement automatically closes the file. You don't have to do `f.close()`

Comment: no, it doesn't print :/  but when I open the profile on twitter I found that he had tweets containing the item

Comment: first make sure `tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name='userScreenName', tweet_mode="extended").items()` is returning a list of items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is about majuscule and minuscule

```
if item.upper() in tweet.upper():
```